# Convert.ToDecimal doesn't convert input decimal number

Tags: c#, decimal

I'm new to c# and tried to convert the input into decimal and double. It works fine when I enter an intiger but stops immediately when I enter a decimal or double number and gives me an "Exception Unhandeled" Error message.

My code:

```
Console.Write("Enter number: ");
decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine(d);
```

So when I enter 3 the program prints out the number 3. But if I enter 3.6, it stops.

I've seen another solution using Double.Parse(); but still can't make my code work.

```
Console.Write("Enter number: ");
decimal d = Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine(d);
```

In my codes I'm using decimal but the same applies to double.

I've tried to look up other questions like this (stackoveflow, google), I've checked out the documentation but couldn't find the issue.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What country are you in? Does your culture use `,` as the decimal separator?

Comment: As @canton7 said, depending on the culture you have `.` or `,` as decimal separator

Comment: `Convert.ToDecimal` and the actual method it calls, `decimal.Parse`, will use the thread's current culture for parsing, based on the user's locale settings. If the input assumes a different culture, parsing will fail. If you don't want to use the current culture, specify the one you want explicitly

Comment: BTW the compiler emits a warning every time you try to use a locale-aware function without passing a `CultureInfo` parameter. It's quite likely the compiler already warned you about the problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos FxCop does, but the compiler itself doesn't

Comment: `I've checked out the documentation but couldn't find the issue` that's explained in the [Globalization and localization section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/globalization-localization/) and separately for each stack (Winforms, WPF, Webforms, MVC etc). Numbers [are explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/globalization-localization/globalization#numeric-values)

Comment: @canton7 I never use FxCop and yet I get those warnings from time to time. Could be a Roslyn analyzer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos FxCop is now distributed as a set of Roslyn analyzers (in `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers`)

Answer (score 3):

All string conversion operations use the current culture, which may differ in things like decimal or thousands separator and other things. You can specify the [invariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture) culture in any of these conversions:

```cs
decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
decimal d = Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Another option is to set the default culture at the start of your application, which will affect all future conversions:

```cs
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you use `decimal` for *finance* you may want to accept not only *decimal* separator, but *group* (thousand) one:

```
   123,456,789.45
```

here `.` is a *decimal* separator when `,` are group ones. To support *group separator* you can specify `NumberStyles.Any`

```
   Console.Write("Enter number: ");

   decimal d;

   while (!Decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), NumberStyles.Any, null, out d)) 
     Console.WriteLine("Invalid syntax. Please, try again.");
```

Please, note that here I've put `null` that stands for `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` which at your workstation seems has `,` for decimal separator and `.` for group one:

```
   "123.45"    -> 12345m   - note, that group separator(s) is/are removed
   "1.2.3.4.5" -> 12345m
   "123,45"    -> 123.45m  - while decimal is turned into decimal point
```

If you want to treat `.` as a *decimal separator* (so `"123.45"` will be parsed into `123.45m`), you can specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
   Console.Write("Enter number: ");

   decimal d;

   while (!Decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), 
                            NumberStyles.Any, 
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                            out d)) 
     Console.WriteLine("Invalid syntax. Please, try again.");
```

Answer (score -3):

As was mentioned in comments, a [decimal separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator?view=netframework-4.8) is varying from country to country. I would suggest to manual replace the entered symbol to the separator used in your culture:

```
string separator = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
decimal d = Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine().Replace(".", separator).Replace(",", separator));
```

Comment: Uh... Why not use the overload of `Decimal.Parse` which takes an `IFormatProvider`, and just pass in `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`? That's the normal way of doing this.

Comment: IMO bad advise, because of hardcoded assumptions on what a decimal separator can be.

Comment: @canton7 After using `decimal d = Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` "6,6" becames "66".

Comment: Yes, because he is Hungarian, not invariant.

Comment: Well yes, you need to use the correct culture for the format of the number entered. If the user is entering using the current culture, use the current culture. If the user is using another culture, or the invariant culture, use that. You can't blindly replace all `.` and `,` characters with the decimal number separator: `1,000.0` will be incorrectly parsed if you do this

Comment: @UweKeim, I didn't see any decimal separators except comma and dot, so I could assume my decision will work in 99% cases

Comment: ... unless the user uses a thousands separator. Do this correctly, and pass the correct culture to `Decimal.Parse`

Comment: @canton7, sorry but `1,000.0` gives me `1000.0` for both comma and dot separators.  ..

Comment: @canton7, oops, now I see it. Thank you.

Comment: @Miamy and South Africa uses `,` for *both* separators. I found that out trying to answer an unusual parsing question. The (unofficial) convention now is to use space for the thousand separator

Comment: Oh, it gets better! [This explains](https://limn.co.za/2013/05/south-african-number-formats/) that the official format isn't common, so the US-style is used. Both Windows 10 and Ubuntu use the official format leading to [unusual situations](https://adrianfrith.com/decimal-comma-ubuntu/)